# Python Flask Pass Global Variable To Blueprint

Tags: python, flask

I am looking into implementing Blueprints but ran into somewhat of a snag.

My app has 3 distinct modules

- Client
- Product
- Order

On the app startup I load 3 global dictionaries one for each module.
The order module uses both the client and the product dictionary, not for making changes but for reference.

How would I go about getting these global dictionaries into each module, seems rather pointless declaring them and then loading them in each Blueprint

Comment: Import them from a separate file? Hard to say more unless you can show a basic example. Maybe something like `routes/client.py` for the blueprint, and `data/client.py` for the dictionary?

Comment: Thanks Peter, basically my main app has a dict var_dict_template_client = OrderedDict().

This dict gets populated by a app route as it could occasionally updated.

I need these dictionaries to be available in every blue print though

Comment: You should ideally be using a database for this - flask apps if hosted online may spawn multiple instances, which would result in a new empty dict for each instance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have global dictionaries that need to be accessed by multiple modules (Client, Product, and Order), you can consider using a shared context or a global object to hold these dictionaries. This way, you don't need to declare and load the dictionaries in each Blueprint separately.

Here's a possible approach:

Create a separate module or file, let's call it `globals.py`, to define and initialize the global dictionaries.

```
 # globals.py

 client_dict = {}
 product_dict = {}
 order_dict = {}
```

In your main application file, import the `globals` module and load the dictionaries.

```
# main.py

from flask import Flask
from globals import client_dict, product_dict, order_dict

app = Flask(__name__)

client_dict = load_client_data()
product_dict = load_product_data()
order_dict = load_order_data()

# Register your Blueprints or modules here

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

In each module or Blueprint that needs access to these dictionaries, import them from the globals module.

```
# client.py

from flask import Blueprint
from globals import client_dict

client_bp = Blueprint('client', __name__)
```

.....

```
# product.py

from flask import Blueprint
from globals import product_dict

product_bp = Blueprint('product', __name__)
```

....

```
# order.py

from flask import Blueprint
from globals import client_dict, product_dict, order_dict

order_bp = Blueprint('order', __name__)
```

By importing the dictionaries from the globals module in each module or Blueprint, you can access and use them directly without the need to declare or load them separately. Any changes made to the dictionaries in one module will be reflected across other modules since they are referencing the same global objects.

Comment: Not having much luck with this, the dictionaries load in the main app, but nothing seems to be passed to the modules

Comment: I think the issue here might be caused by me loading the dictionaries after the blueprint registration, this however needs to be like that as I do occasionally need to update the dictionaries, right now I do this via a a load route

Comment: If I check the more address of the two dict's the one in the main app and the one one the module using print(id(var_dict_clients)) I get different values, so its seems bu just loading the declaration statements in the globals files imply re declares these within the module

Comment: think I found the issue, seems like the var name has to be prefixed with globals. or what ever you called the file you are declaring the variables in

Comment: @WernerVenter is the issue resolved now??

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT